# If $\sigma_b \in S(G)$ such that $\sigma_b(a) = ab$ then show that its signature is $(-1)^{\frac{p-1}{o(b)}}$

Tags: group-theory, field-theory, permutations

I got this exercise from a past term paper, it has three questions, two of whom I think I managed to solve correctly, but I am stuck on the las one.

> Let $p>2$ be a prime number and let $G = \mathbb{F}_p-\{0 \} $. Now let $b \in G$ such that $\sigma_b : G \rightarrow G$ and $$\sigma_b(a)=ab $$

So here's the first question:

> We suppose $p=5$, what is the order of $2$? Show that $\sigma_{2}$ is a cycle.

We have $2^2=4, 2^3=8=3, 2^4=16=1$, thus the order of $2$ is 4. Now in order to show that it's a cycle, I just took all of the elements of $G$ and applied $\sigma_2$ to them, which gave me: $\sigma_2(1)=2, \sigma_2(2)=4, \sigma_2(3)=1,\sigma_2(4)=3$. This $\sigma_2=(1,2,4,3)$, thus it's a cycle. (just out of curiosity, I checked that its signature is $-1$).

Now the second question:

> Once again $p=5$. Calculate the decomposition into disjoint cycles of $\sigma_4$. Is it a cycle?

I did the same thing as in the previous question:
$\sigma_4(1)=4, \sigma_4(2)=3, \sigma_4(3)=2,\sigma_4(4)=1$, thus $\sigma_4=(1,4)(2,3)$, and so it isn't a cycle.(And it's signature is $1$)

Now the last question:

> Show that in general case, the signature of $\sigma_b$ is $$(-1)^{\frac{p-1}{o(b)}}$$ where $o(b)$ is the order of $b$.

And here, I have no idea how to reason. I did see that this works for the permutations in the first two questions, but unsure how to go ahead and prove it.

Comment: More generally, if $g$ is an element of any finite group $G$, and $L_g(x):=gx$ is the left-multiplication map, then $L_g$'s cycles are precisely the right cosets of $\langle g\rangle$, so it is a product of $|G|/|g|$-many disjoint $|g|$-cycles. And an $m$-cycle has sign $(-1)^{m-1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that $\sigma_b$ induces a permutation on the elements of $G$. The length of the cycles is the smallest positive integer $k$ s.t we need to apply $\sigma_b$ $k$ times to get back to the original element. In other words we need to find the smallest $k \in \mathbb{N}$, s.t. $\sigma^k_b(a) = a$. But we have $\sigma^k_b(a) = a\iff ab^k = a \iff b^k = 1 \iff k = \text{ord}(b)$.

So this gives us that all cycles are of length $\text{ord}(b)$ and we have $\frac{p-1}{\text{ord}(b)}$ of them. The signature of each cycle is then $(-1)^{\text{ord}(b)+1}$ and multiplying all $\frac{p-1}{\text{ord}(b)}$  of them we have that the signature of $\sigma_b$ is:

$$\left((-1)^{\text{ord}(b)+1}\right)^{\frac{p-1}{\text{ord}(b)}} = (-1)^{p-1} \cdot (-1)^{\frac{p-1}{\text{ord}(b)}} = (-1)^{\frac{p-1}{\text{ord}(b)}} $$

Comment: Great answer! Thank you!